# Modal no se despliega

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Tengo un problema con las modales de mi sistema.

He creado algunas modales para algunos formularios o selecciones, pero tengo un problema. Al abrirlas en mi maquina y en otras me corre muy bien, pero hay una maquina de escritorio, que al usarla el sistema ahí, no me despliega las modales, solo me queda el fondo gris pero sin mostrar la modal.

Ya revisé si era por la versión de chrome, pero tenemos la misma. No se si el problema será por la máquina de escritorio. Acá comparto el código de una modal que estoy usando.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("empresa");
var boton = document.getElementById("btnAnio");

boton.addEventListener("click",function() {
  $("#empresa").modal('show');
});
```

```css
#grupoTinsa:hover{
        transform: scale(1.1);
        z-index: 2000;
    }
    #grupoTinsa:hover{
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s all ease;
    }

    #americanCleaner:hover{
        transform: scale(1.1);
        z-index: 2000;
    }
    #americanCleaner:hover{
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s all ease;
    }
    .modal-backdrop {
        z-index: 50;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-outline-success text-center" type="button" style="width:100%; height:90px;" id="btnAnio">
    <strong> 2023 </strong>
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="empresa" tabindex="2000" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title w-100 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Selección de empresa</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xlg-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="card" style="padding: 25px;">

                    <input type="hidden" value="2023" id="anioId" name="anioId">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" id="empresaId" name="empresaId">

                        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
                            <div class="col mb-4">
                                <div class="card" id="grupoTinsa">
                                    <center>
                                        <img src="../../../../lib/assets/images/logoTinsa.jpg" alt="TINSA" width="300px" style="padding-top:20px;">
                                    </center>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">GRUPO TINSA</h5>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col mb-4">
                                <div class="card" id="americanCleaner">
                                    <center>
                                        <img src="../../../../lib/assets/images/americanCleaner.png" alt="AMERICAN_CLEANER" width="300px" style="padding-top:10px;">
                                    </center>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">AMERICAN CLEANER</h5>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Si en todos los equipos funciona y en el snippet funciona, el problema es del equipo en sí... Prueba en otros navegadores y con el modo incógnito para descartar alguna configuración o plugin que esté en chrome. Si se soluciona, desinstala chrome y haz una limpieza de archivos residuales y si el problema persiste optaría, en última instancia, por formateo del equipo.